# MySQL Workbench - UPDATE statement using WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a table called 'Rural' - column name 'NO2', with data from another table called 'new_no2' - column name 'NO2'. see the code below

```
update Rural
set Rural.NO2 = new_no2.NO2
where Rural.Year = new_no2.Year
and Rural.Site = new_no2.Site;
```

However, I keep having the error code: 1054. Unknown column 'new_no2.Year' in 'Where clause'

I went through a lot of tutorials and tried loads of things like make sure the table name is correct and so on, but for some reason, it does not work.

It will be great if someone can give some clarity on what I might be doing wrong.

by the way, I'm using MySQL workbench version 8 for MacBook

Thanks
Bruno

Comment: _Small Point_ MySQL Workbench is a tool NOT the database (DBMS) It is MYSQL that is the database. You will find the MYSQL is version 8 and not Workbench. Terminology does matter if you want to be clear in your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub query:

```
update Rural set
Rural.NO2 = coalesce((
    select new_no2.NO2
    from new_no2
    where Rural.Year = new_no2.Year
    and Rural.Site = new_no2.Site), no2)
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6b870e/2).

Use `coalesce()` to leave `no2` unchanged if no corresponding value is found in `new_no2`.

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña what do you mean? This query works: See live demo.

Comment: Forgive me for being pedantic, but what live demo? :)

Comment: @riggs the live demo linked to by clicking the words “live demo” in my answer. If your browser is having trouble rendering this page, the link the the live demo is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6b870e/2

Comment: I see it does now :)